# Suitable Delimitor for one space or more using Node-ETL

Tags: javascript, node.js, etl, business-intelligence, node-etl

Using [`node-etl`](http://github.com/abdennour/etl) , i am able to extract file content into JS array if  ONE space  delimitor :

**data.txt**

```
21 Ahmed UK
54 Jean Chine
65 Mourad Tunisia
```

---

**load.js**

```
var ETL=require('node-etl')
var people=ETL.extract('./data.txt',{
      delimitor:" ", //just ONE Space . What about ONE or many spaces
      headers:["id","name","country"],
 });
 /*
    [
           {id:"21",name:"Ahmed",country:"UK"}, 
           {id:"54",name:"Jean",country:"Chine"},
           {id:"65",name:"Mourad",country:"Tunisia"},      


       ]

 */
```

#### Now, what about if the space between data is not fixed (one or more) ? What is the suitable delimitor ?

**data.txt**

```
21 Ahmed                  UK
54                Jean Chine
65        Mourad     Tunisia
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!

`Node-ETL` package provides some ready static delimitors , for this case , `ETL.DLM_SPACE_OR_MORE` is suitable .

Then , code should be :

```
var people=ETL.extract('./data.txt',{
      delimitor:ETL.DLM_SPACE_OR_MORE, //just ONE Space . What about ONE or many spaces
      headers:["id","name","country"],
 });
 /*
```